Type III ANOVA for linear mixed models using multiply imputed data
I used R to run mixed linear model on a multiply imputed dataset. I'm trying to evaluate the significance of my main effects. I was not able to find a package/function that would allow to compute a type III anova in this particular context.
Some of my data :
structure(list(imp = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), Subj = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 
10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 
15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 
20, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 
13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 
18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 
11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 
16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 
9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 
14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 
19, 20, 20, 20, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 
6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 
12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 
17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 
10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 
15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20
), X1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), levels = c("0", 
"1", "3"), class = "factor"), X2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 
2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), X3 = c(28, 
28, 28, 37, 37, 37, 36, 36, 36, 57, 57, 57, 34, 34, 34, 53, 53, 
53, 42, 42, 42, 25, 25, 25, 29, 29, 29, 21, 21, 21, 52, 52, 52, 
23, 23, 23, 39, 39, 39, 49, 49, 49, 39, 39, 39, 30, 30, 30, 65, 
65, 65, 35, 35, 35, 34, 34, 34, 42, 42, 42, 28, 28, 28, 37, 37, 
37, 36, 36, 36, 57, 57, 57, 34, 34, 34, 53, 53, 53, 42, 42, 42, 
25, 25, 25, 29, 29, 29, 21, 21, 21, 52, 52, 52, 23, 23, 23, 39, 
39, 39, 49, 49, 49, 39, 39, 39, 30, 30, 30, 65, 65, 65, 35, 35, 
35, 34, 34, 34, 42, 42, 42, 28, 28, 28, 37, 37, 37, 36, 36, 36, 
57, 57, 57, 34, 34, 34, 53, 53, 53, 42, 42, 42, 25, 25, 25, 29, 
29, 29, 21, 21, 21, 52, 52, 52, 23, 23, 23, 39, 39, 39, 49, 49, 
49, 39, 39, 39, 30, 30, 30, 65, 65, 65, 35, 35, 35, 34, 34, 34, 
42, 42, 42, 28, 28, 28, 37, 37, 37, 36, 36, 36, 57, 57, 57, 34, 
34, 34, 53, 53, 53, 42, 42, 42, 25, 25, 25, 29, 29, 29, 21, 21, 
21, 52, 52, 52, 23, 23, 23, 39, 39, 39, 49, 49, 49, 39, 39, 39, 
30, 30, 30, 65, 65, 65, 35, 35, 35, 34, 34, 34, 42, 42, 42, 28, 
28, 28, 37, 37, 37, 36, 36, 36, 57, 57, 57, 34, 34, 34, 53, 53, 
53, 42, 42, 42, 25, 25, 25, 29, 29, 29, 21, 21, 21, 52, 52, 52, 
23, 23, 23, 39, 39, 39, 49, 49, 49, 39, 39, 39, 30, 30, 30, 65, 
65, 65, 35, 35, 35, 34, 34, 34, 42, 42, 42, 28, 28, 28, 37, 37, 
37, 36, 36, 36, 57, 57, 57, 34, 34, 34, 53, 53, 53, 42, 42, 42, 
25, 25, 25, 29, 29, 29, 21, 21, 21, 52, 52, 52, 23, 23, 23, 39, 
39, 39, 49, 49, 49, 39, 39, 39, 30, 30, 30, 65, 65, 65, 35, 35, 
35, 34, 34, 34, 42, 42, 42), X4 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), X5 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    Dependant = c(32, 11, 25, 30, 10, 8, 34, NA, NA, 16, 20, 
    20.5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 12, 21, NA, 20, 41, 25, 26, 24, 
    28, 33, 16, 6, 3, 7, 0, NA, 17, 3, NA, 40, 25, 21, 35, NA, 
    NA, 17, 5, 4, 27, 8, 4, 22, 20, NA, 18, 23, 10, 13, 14, 4, 
    15, 12, 14, 32, 11, 25, 30, 10, 8, 34, 22.74679565, 9.078754233, 
    16, 20, 20.5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 12, 21, 23.89331785, 20, 
    41, 25, 26, 24, 28, 33, 16, 6, 3, 7, 0, 9.563034676, 17, 
    3, 8.171110057, 40, 25, 21, 35, 13.53468633, 21.4990267, 
    17, 5, 4, 27, 8, 4, 22, 20, 10.75448127, 18, 23, 10, 13, 
    14, 4, 15, 12, 14, 32, 11, 25, 30, 10, 8, 34, 23.678318, 
    6.38024107, 16, 20, 20.5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 12, 21, 15.33803817, 
    20, 41, 25, 26, 24, 28, 33, 16, 6, 3, 7, 0, 26.37095017, 
    17, 3, 5.8830194, 40, 25, 21, 35, 17.5314952, 13.24750912, 
    17, 5, 4, 27, 8, 4, 22, 20, 16.64639694, 18, 23, 10, 13, 
    14, 4, 15, 12, 14, 32, 11, 25, 30, 10, 8, 34, 24.23722065, 
    14.13450552, 16, 20, 20.5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 12, 21, 21.8956743, 
    20, 41, 25, 26, 24, 28, 33, 16, 6, 3, 7, 0, 13.31806771, 
    17, 3, 12.46910086, 40, 25, 21, 35, 5.346067919, 14.71408964, 
    17, 5, 4, 27, 8, 4, 22, 20, 9.644988209, 18, 23, 10, 13, 
    14, 4, 15, 12, 14, 32, 11, 25, 30, 10, 8, 34, 16.25464311, 
    14.55203722, 16, 20, 20.5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 12, 21, 20.15197466, 
    20, 41, 25, 26, 24, 28, 33, 16, 6, 3, 7, 0, 7.169741223, 
    17, 3, 15.89606111, 40, 25, 21, 35, 8.178602917, -2.653330003, 
    17, 5, 4, 27, 8, 4, 22, 20, 17.11276677, 18, 23, 10, 13, 
    14, 4, 15, 12, 14, 32, 11, 25, 30, 10, 8, 34, 28.30217443, 
    7.983293096, 16, 20, 20.5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 12, 21, -2.445506679, 
    20, 41, 25, 26, 24, 28, 33, 16, 6, 3, 7, 0, 0.897162825, 
    17, 3, 12.38497675, 40, 25, 21, 35, 13.76105932, 23.24251938, 
    17, 5, 4, 27, 8, 4, 22, 20, 9.744084982, 18, 23, 10, 13, 
    14, 4, 15, 12, 14), X6 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -360L), variable.labels = c(imp = "", 
Subj = "", X1 = "Temps", X2 = "PsychoT1", X3 = "T0_age", X4 = "Group", 
X5 = "Sexe", Dependant = "Dependant", X6 = "PsychoT0"), codepage = 65001L, class = "data.frame")

The models I tried :
library(foreign)
library(mice)
library(broom.mixed)
library(lme4)
library(datawizard)
library(mitml)
library(car)

df1 <- datawizard::to_factor(df1, c("X1", "X2", "X4", "X5", "X6"))

df.mids1<-as.mids(long=df1, .imp="imp")

implist1 <- mids2mitml.list(df.mids1)

Lmer.X2<-with(implist1, lmer(Dependant ~ X1*X2*X4 +
                                   (1| Subj)))

Lmer.X21 <- with(data = df.mids1, exp = lme4::lmer(Dependant ~ X1*X2*X4 +(1| Subj)), reml=TRUE)

car::Anova(Lmer.X21)
#> Error in UseMethod("vcov"): pas de méthode pour 'vcov' applicable pour un objet de classe "c('mira', 'matrix')"

car::Anova(Lmer.X2)
#> Error in UseMethod("vcov"): pas de méthode pour 'vcov' applicable pour un objet de classe "c('mitml.result', 'list')"


Correct me if I'm wrong, but

miceadds::mi.anova does not seem to be able to handle linear mixed model;
car::Anova does not seem to handle mira or mitml class dataset

I found alternative options based on model comparisons like TestModels of the mitml package which is based on the D3 LRT method (Meng and Rubin, 1992), but I'm not quite sure how to implement the model comparison to test the significance of all individual fixed effects. I'm new to R and this kind of model with interactions so I was hoping for a package/function that could directly compute the anova.

When new to R and the kind of model, don't miss out on CrossValidated for the theoretical part. StackOverflow primarily helps with programming issues, R language or other, as such.

Thank you for your comment. I posted on CrossValidated to know more about nested models with interaction, but I thought here was the place for the coding aspect and if there was function/package/code snippets available to do the ANOVA in this particular context.

I think you should show a minimal reproducible example here. From what you have posted it shows your fit_PHQ9Benzo object is of class "c('mira', 'matrix')", which is not really normal if it comes from lmer(). So I think the error is from your code.

@LiangZhang sorry for the confusion, I tried two packages. I copy-pasted the error from my other tests where it gave me Mira object. You are right that the model above gave me a mitml object, because I used the mitml package for this one. I'll add the mitml error and a reprex as well as soon as I have access to my computer!
